# Какая вероятность что из 5 карт 4 будут одной масти?

Tags: математика, случайные-числа, теория-вероятностей, вычислительный-эксперимент

Есть колода с бесконечным числом карт, вытягиваем оттуда 5 карт. Какая вероятность что из 5-и 4 будут одной масти?

Посчитал на пальцах - выходит 0,015625% (может быть и неправильно), но интересно узнать какой формулой нужно считать в таком задании, ведь задание может быть и очень трудным и тут уже без формулы никак

Comment: Ваши пальцы преувеличивают ) Формула есть погуглите Вероятность совместных независимых событий.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ну, давайте соображать. Пусть мы выбираем конкретную масть, и какова вероятность, что таких карт - 4? Вероятность вынуть одну карту "не такую" - 3/4, и "такую" - 1/4. При этом пять вариантов размещения "не такой" карты - первой, второй ... пятой. Итого, вероятность вынуть пять карт, из которых 4 - нужной масти - 5*(3/4)*(1/4)^4.

Мастей - 4, события взаимоисключающие, так что просто можно сложить вероятности, т.е. умножить на 4.

Итак -

```
5*3*(1/4)^4 ~ 5.86%
```

[Вычислительный эксперимент](https://ideone.com/uFwxSI) подтверждает :)

Готовых формул на все случаи жизни не существует... Данная ситуация называется [мультиномиальным распределением](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), но оно же будет у вас не всегда :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ, красиво разъяснили, только одно не понятно, зачем мы в конце умножаем на 4? Я посчитал так - 4 мастей,назначим от 0 до 3.Наши  варианты 
 00001,00002,00003,00010,00020,00030,00100,00200,00300,01000,02000,03000,10000,20000,30000. 15 вариантов, если поделить на возможные 1024 и умножить на ваше "4" то как раз получается 5.86%. Но разве кроме перечисленных вариантов есть еще другие варианты?

Comment: Потому что рассуждения выше - для **конкретной** масти, скажем, для треф. И их надо выполнить 4 раза :) - для **каждой** масти. Ведь четыре пики - не то, что четыре трефы... Ведь в варианте 00001 первая карта у вас может быть любой, грубо говоря - она вынимается с вероятностью не 1/4, а 1 :)

Comment: @Mangust Karl: Вы все правильно посчитали, только кроме `0000...` у вас еще должно быть все то же самое для `1111...`, `2222...` и `3333...`, Количество вариантов очевидно равно 60, как я написал в ответе ниже, а не 15 , и ответ - 60/1024.

Comment: Простите, вышло недоразумение, забыл написать что масть должно быть только сердце. С указанными условиями все правильно написали!!!

Comment: @Mangust Karl: Но это уже совсем другое условие. Если общая масть заранее фиксирована, то тогда вы уже все правильно посчитали. Правильный ответ - именно 15/1024 = 0.0146484375.

Answer (score 2):

Задача легко решается "в лоб", простым подсчетом количества всевозможных равновероятных исходов эксперимента.

Количество вариантов размещения 4 мастей по 5 позициям равно 4<sup>5</sup> = 1024.

- Если под "4 карты одной масти" имеется в виду "ровно 4, любой, но одинаковой масти", то количество интересующих нас вариантов равно количеству размещений двух разных мастей (4 * 3 = 12), умноженному на количество размещений вида "4 одинаковых, 1 отличная" (5). Итого: 12 * 5 = 60 интересующих нас вариантов. Вероятность равна 60 / 1024 = 0.05859375
- Если под "4 карты одной масти" имеется в виду "ровно 4, одной конкретной, заранее заданной масти", то количество интересующих нас вариантов равно количеству вариантов пятой карты (3), умноженному на количество размещений вида "4 одинаковых, 1 отличная" (5). Итого: 3 * 5 = 15 интересующих нас вариантов. Вероятность равна 15 / 1024 = 0.0146484375

Если же под "4 карты" подразумевается "найдется хотя бы 4 карты одной масти", то количество интересующих нас вариантов в первом случае увеличивается на 4, а во втором - на 1. Вероятности меняются соответствующим образом.